# URLSearchParams returning null for the first query string

Tags: javascript, html

Why is timeperiod null

```js
const url = 'http://example.com?timeperiod=lasttwentyeightdays&pagesize=20'
const args =  new URLSearchParams(url);
alert('timeperiod='+args.get('timeperiod') + ' and pagesize='+ args.get('pagesize'));
```

But in the below code it works

```js
  const url = 'http://example.com?x=c&timeperiod=lasttwentyeightdays&pagesize=20'
  const args =  new URLSearchParams(url);
  alert('timeperiod='+args.get('timeperiod') + ' and pagesize='+ args.get('pagesize'));
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to create an URL object and then retrieve the params with url.search : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams#Examples

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to create a URL object and then retrieve the params with `url.search`:

[See](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams#Examples)

```js
const url = new URL('http://example.com?timeperiod=lasttwentyeightdays&pagesize=20');

const args =  new URLSearchParams(url.search);

console.log(`timeperiod=${args.get('timeperiod')} and pagesize=${ args.get('pagesize')}`);
```

Comment: If you want your current site's query params, then use document.location.search.

Comment: Or simply [`url.searchParams`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams).

Answer (score 0):

one liner with slight changes for ES6,

```
const caller = new URLSearchParams(URL(decodeURIComponent(import.meta.url)).search).get('pagesize');
```