# JavaScript URL searchParams not returning anything

Tags: javascript, url

I'm trying to run this in the latest version of Chrome (75.0.3770.142), but I'm not getting any search parameters.  For example:

```
let params = (new URL("http://blah.com?q=something")).searchParams;
```

This is just returning an empty object, so the query string hasn't been parsed.  I've tried multiple examples but they all return an empty object.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `.searchParams.get("q")`

Comment: This is a duplicate of [URLSearchParams returning null for the first query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55103757/urlsearchparams-returning-null-for-the-first-query-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get all URL parameters, try using `searchParams.toString()`:

```js
var params = (new URL('http://blah.com?q=something')).searchParams.toString();
console.log(params);
```

To get a specific value by a parameter name, use `searchParams.get('q')`:

```js
var params = (new URL('http://blah.com?q=something')).searchParams.get('q');
console.log(params);
```

Comment: OK, so adding toString() has returned a string, but I need something iterable.  From reading the documentation it states it should return an object?

Comment: It returns an object, of all available functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
const url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=test&rlz=1C1CHBF_enVN867VN867&oq=test&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l4j69i61j69i60j69i65.1415j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8";
const foo = new URL(url);
const searchParams = Object.fromEntries(Array(...foo.searchParams.entries()));
console.log(searchParams);
```